# Moving Sitemesh3.xml to a different folder

Tags: configuration, sitemesh

I'm practicing web programming by using Spring 3.1, Hibernate and SiteMesh3.

I want to move 'sitemesh3.xml' file to other directory as WEB-INF/spring/ (not in WEB-INF directly). I've tried it, but sitemesh didn't work. Is it possible to move it? If it is, what properties, if any, should I add on other files like web.xml?

(I've read http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh3/Configuring+SiteMesh+3, which says "The configuration file should live in /WEB-INF/sitemesh3.xml in your web-application.")

Comment: Why exactly don't you want it in `WEB-INF` directly, as the instructions say to?

Comment: if it is editable, I want to get all xml files together in one directory. except for web.xml

Comment: To what purpose and for what reason? Because it looks tidy? Because you want to lump them together for processing? Or what?

Comment: just a simple reason, if all setting files placed at one directory,  it's easy to manage and look tidy as you said.
others can move it, but only sitemesh3.xml can't....

Answer (score 0):

Consider using java config, you can get rid of xml configuration totally.
Follow [Sitemesh Java Config](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh3/Configuring+SiteMesh+3)

Create a filter like this and register it in your web.xml or in java configuration file.

```
   @WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
     public class ConfiguredSiteMeshFilter extends ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter {
        @Override
        protected void applyCustomConfiguration(SiteMeshFilterBuilder builder) {
            builder.addDecoratorPath("/*", "/WEB-INF/decorators/defaultDecorator.jsp");
        }
    }
```